# Swift - One to Many relationsthips in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm just starting to learn Swift, coming from Java and .NET, and it's really different, I want to create a small app using Core Data, I have two tables: Clinic and Doctor, where a clinic can have one or more doctors, so I need a one to many relationship, this is what I've done so far:

[image]

Relations:

[image]

[image]

I have added DoctorId and ClinicId as indexes in the Clinic table and DoctorId in the Doctor table. My question is, at this point, am I telling Swift that the relations are Clinic.doctorId == Doctor.doctorId and that the Clinic table can have more than one Doctor? I would expect to see a place where I could tell Swift which attributes to use as link. Am I missing something? I would appreciate your guidance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any other attributes to assign the relationship - the relationship exists separately of any other items. Also, your relationship name is backwards - on Clinic, it should be named `doctors`, and on Doctor, it should be `clinic`. To assign the relationship, do this:

```
let doctorOne = Doctor(...)
let doctorTwo = Doctor(...)
let clinic = Clinic(...)
//assign either way - first way is more logical and makes more sense (especially as Core Data relationships are default optional)
doctorOne.clinic = clinic
doctorTwo.clinic = clinic
//or
clinic.doctors = Set<doctorOne, doctorTwo>
```

Comment: I changed the relations name. Could you explain the code above a little bit? then I can keep investigating from that point. So, what you mean is that the relation between fields is only made by code? at which point of the application logic? Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation here - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html